# flexbox and grid layout questions

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I've started to learn html and css, and I have big issues with layout, I tried grid and flexbox. What I want to achieve is this:

What layout I try to have
[image]

And sadly, my website looks like this:

My lay out look like this
[image]

Now here's my code, and please explain like you would explain to a braindead if you're willing to, thanks in advance and have a nice day.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1.0"/>
  <title>PE-ZONA.RO | WEBTOONS </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css"/>
 </head>

<body>
<!-- HEADER - ICONIȚE -->
<header>
 <div class="mhcon">
  <div class="mhconitem"><a href="#">PATREON</a></div>
  <div class="mhconitem2"><a href="#">DISCORD</a></div>
 </div>
</header>

<!-- SIDEBAR-NAVIGATIE -->
<aside>
   <nav>
     <div id="sidebar">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">WEBTOONS</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">ECHIPĂ</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">ALĂTURĂ-TE</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
<aside>

<!-- WEBTOONS -->
<section>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>NUME WEBTOON1</h3> <br>
    <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>NUME WEBTOON2</h3> <br>
    <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h3>NUME WEBTOON3</h3> <br>
    <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON
  </div>
 </div>
</section>

<!-- FOOTER -->
<footer>
 <div class="footercon">
  <p>Copyright @ pe-zona.ro</p>
 </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>



   /* ARTICOLE */
.card {
  background-color: #c4c4;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 6px solid #c5c5;
}


/* CONTAINER MENIU HEADER */
.mhcon {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid red;
  order: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

/* PATREON BUTTON */
.mhconitem {
  margin: 25px 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f07167;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
}

.mhconitem a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* DISCORD BUTTON */
.mhconitem2 {
  margin: 25px 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #6a4c93;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
}

.mhconitem2 a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* CONTAINER SIDEBAR */
#sidebar {
 background-color: black;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 25vh;
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
}

/* CONTAINER CONTENT */
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 2;
}

/* CONTAINER FOOTER */
.footercon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.footercon p {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I have created a Grid Layout for you. Please have a lot. And do accept the answer if it helps by clicking the tick icons on left side of my answer. This will help other coders with the same grid issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CSS-Grids`, Your layout is ready :)

> CSS-Grids offer lots of flexibility to create such layouts rather than
> by using flex-boxes.

**CODEPEN LINK:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/abmEBgP

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  gap: 1rem;

  grid-template-areas:
    "aside section section section"
    "aside section section section"
    "aside section section section"
    "aside section section section"
    "aside section section section"
    "aside section section section"
    "aside footer footer footer"
    "aside footer footer footer";
}

aside,
header,
footer,
section {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
aside {
  grid-area: aside;
}

section {
  grid-area: section;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  padding: 2rem;

  grid-template-areas:
    " header header header"
    "content content content"
    "content content content"
    "content content content"
    "content content content"
    "content content content";
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  border: none;
}

header .mhcon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

header .mhcon div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

header .mhcon div:last-child {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-area: content;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 2rem;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name"viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1.0"/>
    <title>PE-ZONA.RO | WEBTOONS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- SIDEBAR-NAVIGATIE -->
    <aside>
      <nav>
        <div id="sidebar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">WEBTOONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ECHIPĂ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ALĂTURĂ-TE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </aside>

    <!-- WEBTOONS -->
    <section>
      <!-- HEADER - ICONIȚE -->
      <header>
        <div class="mhcon">
          <div class="mhconitem"><a href="#">PATREON</a></div>
          <div class="mhconitem2"><a href="#">DISCORD</a></div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="card">
          <h3>NUME WEBTOON1</h3>
          <br />
          <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h3>NUME WEBTOON2</h3>
          <br />
          <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h3>NUME WEBTOON3</h3>
          <br />
          <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h3>NUME WEBTOON1</h3>
          <br />
          <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h3>NUME WEBTOON2</h3>
          <br />
          <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON</p>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <h3>NUME WEBTOON3</h3>
          <br />
          <p>DESCRIERE WEBTOON</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer>
      <div class="footercon">
        <p>Copyright @ pe-zona.ro</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```